# Video abstracts for mathematical papers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ho.history-overview

I recently published a video abstract of a manuscript of mine (number theory), finding that more people are interested in its content than when I uploaded the preprint on arXiv.
Now, my main question is: "What kind of requirements should a video abstract meet in order to improve the content of the standard abstract written at the beginning of the paper?".

As an example, we could edit the video by adding transitions, 3D animations, and Figures, while we are also free to rearrange complex formulae written on the board by hand.
Moreover, I think that even 4:30 minutes of recording could be easily reduced to less than 4 minutes, by cutting pauses and breathing, meeting the standard length requirement for a video abstract.

Do you have any references about how to create good video abstracts and which NT journals include them, by any chance?